# Cosa significa "fessato" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> E io sono andato fin su... arrampicandomi gattoni su 
>   un dosso e raspando con le unghie da una zanca **fessata**... ho cavato una manciata di terra… l’ho annusata: dolce, grassa!

Non capisco il significato di "fessata" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato "fessato" e "fessare", ma non ho trovato questi vocaboli sui dizionari. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La parola da cercare in questo caso è *fesso* (l'aggettivo, non il sostantivo!)

> **fésso¹** agg. e s. m. [part. pass. di *fendere*; lat. *fĭssus*, part. pass. di *findĕre*]. – 1. agg. **a.** Spaccato, diviso con un taglio: *Dinanzi a me sen va piangendo Alì, Fesso nel volto dal mento al ciuffetto* (Dante); più com., di recipienti, incrinato: *pentola, brocca f.*; *conca f.* (questo anche fig., di persona malaticcia, e così nel prov. *dura più una conca f. che una sana*); *porta invece un altro fiasco, perché questo è f.* (Manzoni), vuoto, come se perdesse da un’incrinatura
>
> Dal [Dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fesso1/)

In particolare è usato nell'espressione *zoccolo fesso* per indicare la particolare zampa di alcuni animali in cui lo zoccolo è diviso in due.